# decorator @bot.tree.command in Cog

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How should I use decorator @bot.tree.command in class?

My main file:

```
import os
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

extens = ["cogs.slash_commands"]


class MyBot(commands.Bot):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix='/', intents=discord.Intents.all())

    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'{self.user} is now running!')
        for cog in extens:
            try:
                await bot.load_extension(cog)
                print(f"{cog} was loaded.")
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
bot = MyBot()
load_dotenv()
bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

And my cog look like this

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands


class SlashCommands(commands.Cog):
    
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.tree.command
    async def hello(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, thing_to_say: str):
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"{thing_to_say}")


async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(SlashCommands(bot))
```

When I compile it says:

> Extension 'cogs.slash_commands' raised an error: AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands' has no attribute 'tree'

What should I do? What should I add in my main file and edit in my cog file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a slash command in a cogs class, we use the [@app_commands.command()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.command) decorator.

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands


class SlashCommands(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @app_commands.command()
    async def hello(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, thing_to_say: str):
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"{thing_to_say}")


async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(SlashCommands(bot))
```

This is similar to how we add prefix commands in cogs with the [@commands.command()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.command) decorator. This is because we are not just adding a singular command to the command tree like with [bot.tree.command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.CommandTree.command), we are adding the entire Cog class with the commands inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

`discord.ext.commands` doesn't have the tree attribute, your `bot` does.

In my code, without classes, I use

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all()) 
#make sure your bot variable is correctly being assigned to the intents 

@bot.event #dont forget this in your code
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is now running!')
    try:
        synced = await bot.tree.sync() #should be the same as your cog system
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

#accessing the tree within the bot, not the tree within the commands
@bot.tree.command(name="website", description="Get the link to our website")
async def website(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("https://www.stackoverflow.com")
```